# Authorization in react-redux. Container Component receives props ( isLoggedIn) before decoded token will be set to store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When the user visits the site, I want to check jwtToken in localStorage and if it is valid, the user will be redirected to the home page.

But ContainerComponent receives props (with **isLoggedIn** prop)  before decoding token and setting data to store. Can I fix it somehow?

Below my code for checking token:

**index.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
  const store = configureStore();
  //Check for token
  if (token) {
    // Set auth token header auth
    API.setAuthToken(token);
    // Decode token and get user info and exp
    const decoded = await jwt_decode(token);
    // Check for expired token
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
    if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
      // Logout user
      await store.dispatch(logoutUser());
      // Redirect to login
      window.location.href = "/auth";
    } else {
      await store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(token));
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
});
```

The **setCurrentUser** action  is here:

```
// Logged in
export const authUser = (userData) => (dispatch) =>
  API.auth(userData).then(
    (res) => {
      const token = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      API.setAuthToken(token);
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "Secret");
      dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(decoded));
    },
    (err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      })
  );


// Check login
export const authSuccess = (token) => (dispatch) => {
  if (token) {
    API.setAuthToken(token);
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "Secret");
    console.log("decoded", decoded);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  } else {
    dispatch(logoutCurrentUser());
  }
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = (decoded) => {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded,
  };
};

// Session reducer
const _nullUser = Object.freeze({
  id: null,
});

const sessionReducer = (state = _nullUser, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        username: action.payload.username,
        id: action.payload._id,
        email: action.payload.email,
        position: action.payload.position,
      };
    case LOGOUT_CURRENT_USER:
      return _nullUser;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default sessionReducer;
```

I check the **isLoggedIn**   in the page container component

```
import AuthPage from "./authPage";
import { authSuccess } from "../../actions/session.actions";
import { authUser } from "../../actions/session.actions";

class AuthPageContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <AuthPage
          authSuccess={this.props.authSuccess}
          authUser={this.props.authUser}
          isLoggedIn={this.props.isLoggedIn}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: Boolean(state.Session),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { authUser, authSuccess })(
  AuthPageContainer
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problem! Instead of dispatching thunk-function I dispatch  plain  object

**before:** `store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(token))`
**after:** `store.dispatch(authSuccess(token))`